# SQL: How to filter to return only the rows from a result set where certain data in a field appears in more than one row of the unfiltered result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have this data:

```
code1 code2
  1    10       <-- Desired (1 appears more than once)
  1    11       <-- Desired (1 appears more than once)
  2    20
  3    30       <-- Desired (3 appears more than once)
  3    31       <-- Desired (3 appears more than once)
  4    40
  5    50
```

... And I want to write a **single SQL query** whose results are this:

```
code1 code2
  1    10       <-- This result appears because 1 appears more than once above
  1    11       <-- This result appears because 1 appears more than once above
  3    30       <-- This result appears because 3 appears more than once above
  3    31       <-- This result appears because 3 appears more than once above
```

(i.e, a single SQL query that returns all rows for which any data in the `code1` column appears more than once)...

What SQL can I write?  Is it possible?

Here is what I have so far, which does not work:

```
// WARNING!
// INVALID SQL

SELECT 
  code1,
  code2 
FROM
  mytable 
GROUP BY code1,
  code2 
HAVING COUNT(code1) > 1    <-- This line is invalid

// WARNING!
// INVALID SQL
```

Rather than continuing to fight with it... I thought I would ask on StackOverflow.  Thanks!

(Any MySQL-specific commands are ALLOWED, if they might help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
SELECT code1, code2
FROM myTable
WHERE code1 IN 
    (SELECT code1 FROM myTable GROUP BY code1 HAVING COUNT(code1) > 1)
```

or using `INNER JOIN` like this :

```
SELECT t.code1, code2
FROM myTable t
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT code1 FROM myTable GROUP BY code1 HAVING COUNT(code1) > 1)
     s on s.code1 = t.code1
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae2c5/1)

Comment: Optional next question: How to optimize if `myTable` has ~30000 rows, with only about 400 duplicate groups, and almost always just 2 entries per duplicate group.  On my MySQL instance running on a high-end workstation, this takes ~5 minutes to execute.

Comment: updated with other option: using `INNER JOIN`. But not sure if that better performance-wise :p I'm not experienced on this topic (query optimization)

Comment: Wow - that query ran almost instantly.  *Update* from previous comment that the first query took 30 minutes, not 5 minutes, on my high-end workstation.  I may investigate why the second is thousands of times more efficient, or post another question about it.  Thanks!

Comment: I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723017/join-vs-where-why-do-two-queries-that-obtain-identical-results-exhibit-3-4-ord to ask about the gigantic performance difference, which isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: possible logical reason I can think is: in the 1st query, subquery in where clause executed multiple times (for each row maybe). But in the 2nd query it is only executed once to construct joined table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a select distinct here. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code1, from mytable ... HAVING COUNT(code1) > 1
```

Edited to say that this will only work if you want to return only the code1 field. If you also want to return the code2 field, this will fail and return you multiples since their joint values is what DISTINCT will go against.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: That's the issue I was running into also ... I *do* want to see the `code2` field - in fact, that's the main purpose of my query (so I can see these duplicates).