# Benchmarking INNER JOIN vs SUBSELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Generally speaking, is there a rule of thumb of when to use a subselect and when to use an inner join? For me, it is usually a coin flip because I don't really understand the internals.

When should I use which?

```
SELECT item1, item2 FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.field=table2.field
```

Or -

```
SELECT item1, item2 FROM table1 WHERE field in
    (SELECT field FROM table2)
```

Comment: Mysql handles the latter worse, especially in older versions. So the rule: 1. prefer `INNER JOIN` 2. Use the newest version you can afford

Comment: Study case where `INNER JOIN` version took only a fraction of a second and the subquery took almost 30 minutes : [JOIN vs. WHERE: Why do two queries that obtain identical results exhibit 3-4 orders of magnitude performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723017/join-vs-where-why-do-two-queries-that-obtain-identical-results-exhibit-3-4-ord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a comparable sub-query version should be:

```
SELECT item1, item2 FROM table1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table.field = table2.field)
```

In RDBMS with a strong query optimizer they should be indistinguishable since one could be automatically converted to another. Apparently MySQL is not in that league yet and `JOIN` outperforms correlated sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Normally JOINs are faster than subquery

When result set of subquery is very minimal , subquery might be faster.

Also this depends on the RDBMS optimization.